# Is it possible to assign a hotkey on the checkbox

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, 3d-view

For example I want to assign on the checkbox "Wire" hot key F4
Can I do it?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. Go to your **User Preferences**, Section **Input**, and navigate to 3D View, Object Mode:

[image: Object Mode Hotkeys]

Then, add a hotkey for Object Mode only, and use these settings:

- Operator Name: **wm.context_toggle**
- Hotkey: **F4**
- Context Attribute: **object.show_wire**

[image: attributes]

This Operator allows you to toggle many boolean properties if they are accessible reliably via Python. You can test it by going to a Python console and typing in:

```
bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path='object.show_wire')
```

The **object.show_wire** part is referring to the **Active Object**, searching for a property called **show_wire** on it. so if you try this instead, the X-Ray Property will be toggled instead:

```
bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path='object.show_x_ray')
```

If you want to have the operator working for any mode in the 3D View, add the shortcut under the **3D View Global** section.

Comment: @R_M_S Apologies for the confusion. A long time ago I had coded my own operator to toggle these properties for all selected objects. I did reset Blender to factory settings before testing my initial answer, but the operator was still around for some reason. I edited my answer for a general working solution which works on the active object only.

Comment: aliasguru 
Thanks A lot . Now It works!
Is it possible to do in any way, so that whenI press the F4 automatically is activated function 'Draw All Edges'
Or for do it I need to create a individual hotkey?
http://s16.postimg.org/xk4wmznp1/7_M_X_pe_XN.jpg

Comment: @R_M_S It's better to assign a different shortcut to it. I tried mapping the Wire toggle to 'Press' and the Draw_All_Edges toggle to 'Release', but I get a glitch then. The Draw_All_Edges is activated and Deactivated right after that. However, Draw_All_Edges is something you only need to set once anyways. Maybe it's better if you select all Mesh items in your scene, make one the active object, and Alt+Click on the 'draw all edges' checkbox? This will turn on that mode for every selected object at once.